# Can't use DB_NAME : Access denied for user

Tags: php, mysql, html, forms

I am trying to make a contact form and connected to the database and the error
keep telling me i can't access to the table in the database
I have been strggleing almost for 7 hours and I am really tired
any help guys
[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cg0lr.png)

[table image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TpZKz.png)

```html
<?php
$DB_NAME = "form";
$DB_USER = "root";
$DB_PASSWORD = "";
$DB_HOST = "localhost";

 $link = mysql_connect($DB_HOST,$DB_USER,$DB_PASSWORD,$DB_NAME);

 if (!$link){
  die("could not connect:" . mysql_error());
 };


 $db_selected = mysql_select_db($DB_NAME,$link);

 if(!$db_selected) {
  die("Can\'t use " . $DB_NAME . ' : ' . mysql_error());
 };

 $value = $_POST["user_name"]; // required
 $value2 = $_POST["user_eamil"];// required
 $value3 = $_POST["subject"];
 $value4 = $_POST["text_massege"];// required
 

 
 $sql = "INSERT INTO form (user_name , user_eamil , subject , text_massege) VALUES ('$value','$value2','$value3','$value4')";

 if (!mysql_query($sql)){
  die("Error: " . mysql_error());
 };


 // Build the email (replace the address in the $to section with your own)
 $email_from = $value2;//<== update the email address
 $email_subject = "New Form submission";
 $email_body = "You have received a new message from the user $value.\n".
     "Here is the message:\n $value4".
     
 $to = "mail";//<== update the email address
 $headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
 $headers .= "Reply-To: $value2 \r\n";
  

 if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$value)) {
   $nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
 }
 //Send the email!
 mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
 //done. redirect to thank-you page.
 header('Location: thank-you.html');


 // Function to validate against any email injection attempts
  function IsInjected($str)
  {
    $injections = array('(\n+)',
                '(\r+)',
                '(\t+)',
                '(%0A+)',
                '(%0D+)',
                '(%08+)',
                '(%09+)'
                );
    $inject = join('|', $injections);
    $inject = "/$inject/i";
    if(preg_match($inject,$str))
      {
      return true;
    }
    else
      {
      return false;
    }
  }
 mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: first notes seems like you have password set for database root for db:form and if not it seems like you are reselecting the db in mysql_select_db() statement

Comment: Are you sure the database is called `form`, your table is called `form` are they both the same? Otherwise this is simply a database permission issue, and you don't have access to this database.

Comment: I suggest you to use `mysqli` as `mysql` is deprecated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<?php
$DB_NAME = "form";//Database name
$DB_USER = "root";
$DB_PASSWORD = "";
$DB_HOST = "localhost";

$link = mysql_connect($DB_HOST,$DB_USER,$DB_PASSWORD,$DB_NAME);

if (!$link){
    die("could not connect:" . mysql_error());
};


$db_selected = mysql_select_db($DB_NAME,$link);

if(!$db_selected) {
    die("Can\'t use " . $DB_NAME . ' : ' . mysql_error());
};

if (isset($_POST["user_name"])) {
    $value = $_POST["user_name"]; // required
    $value2 = $_POST["user_eamil"];// required
    $value3 = $_POST["subject"];
    $value4 = $_POST["text_massege"];// required


    //Please use table name here
    $sql = "INSERT INTO form (user_name , user_eamil , subject , text_massege) VALUES ('$value','$value2','$value3','$value4')";

    if (!mysql_query($sql)){
        die("Error: " . mysql_error());
    };


    // Build the email (replace the address in the $to section with your own)
    $email_from = $value2;//<== update the email address
    $email_subject = "New Form submission";
    $email_body = "You have received a new message from the user $value.\n".
        "Here is the message:\n $value4".

    $to = "mail";//<== update the email address
    $headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: $value2 \r\n";


    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$value)) {
      $nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
    }
    //Send the email!
    mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
    //done. redirect to thank-you page.
    header('Location: thank-you.html');


    // Function to validate against any email injection attempts
        function IsInjected($str)
        {
          $injections = array('(\n+)',
                      '(\r+)',
                      '(\t+)',
                      '(%0A+)',
                      '(%0D+)',
                      '(%08+)',
                      '(%09+)'
                      );
          $inject = join('|', $injections);
          $inject = "/$inject/i";
          if(preg_match($inject,$str))
            {
            return true;
          }
          else
            {
            return false;
          }
        }
    mysql_close();
}
?>

<form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="user_name" >
    <input type="text" name="user_eamil" >
    <input type="text" name="subject" >
    <input type="text" name="text_massege" >
    <input type="submit" value="submit" >
</form>
```

Comment: Can you explain what changes you made that makes you believe this will work?

Comment: MY man you are the one , the problem is I was using the name of the table not the name of the database .

Comment: I don't think answer is relevant to question which is actual issue that is can't connect to database. But answer is accepted... wondering how???